# api gateway and lambda pagination

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to do an api using AWS Api Gateway as a Lambda trigger.
Lambda is implemented in python 3.7.
When I submit a POST to api URL, a Lambda is triggered and the code implemented returns an array of JSON.
Example of response:

```
[
  {
    "k1": 1,
    "k2": 2
  },
  {
    "k3": 3,
    "k4": 4
  },
  {
    "k5": 5,
    "k6": 6
  },
  {
    "k7" : 7,
    "k8" : 8
  }
]
```

In example, lambda response will be a list of 4 json objects. I want to paginate the response to send one object in each page.
Is it possible? How can I told the api or lambda which is the complete array?

Answer (score 0):

After investigate this topic, I wasn't able to paginate the response in the api so I paginate the response in my code. My code reads data from database so I pass a token to api to check in which line of database I am reading

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).